# Table unnecessarily starting from next page in latex

Tags: latex, texnic-center

How can I stop my table in latex to start unnecessarily from next page leaving a huge space in previous page? How can I force to start just after the heading. Here is my code:

I am using packages:

```latex
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption},
\usepackage{float}
```

and the code for my table is:

```latex
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{| l| l }
$.$ & Matches any character.\\ 
$*$ & Matches zero or more instances of the previous pattern item.\\
$+$ & Matches one or more instances of the previous pattern item.\\
$?$ & Matches zero or one instances of the previous pattern item.\\
$( )$ & Groups a subpattern. The repetition and alternation operators apply to the preceding subpattern.\\
$|$ & Alternation.\\
$[ ]$ & Delimit a set of characters. Ranges are specified as [x-y].\\
\textasciicircum & Anchor the pattern to the beginning of the string. Only when first.\\
\$ & Anchor the pattern to the end of the string. Only when last.\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I tried `[!ht]`, `[!htp]` and `[htpb]` nothing of that sort works instead the table vanishes.

Comment: Hi! Please post a code that can be compiled, this is including `\documentclass{...}` and `\begin{document} ... \end{document}`. Only with such code reproducing the problem it is possible to give you a focused answer.

Comment: You will find your answers here: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/Qzz31); [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://goo.gl/290dD)

Answer (score 0):

Not only in the case that your table is too long to vertically fit into the page (e.g. below a header or some text paragraph), you can switch from the float approach to:

```latex
%\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l}
    %
  \endfirsthead
    %
  \endhead
    %
  \endfoot
    %
  \endlastfoot
    $.$ & Matches any character.\\ 
    $*$ & Matches zero or more instances of the previous pattern item.\\
    $+$ & Matches one or more instances of the previous pattern item.\\
    $?$ & Matches zero or one instances of the previous pattern item.\\
    $( )$ & Groups a subpattern. The repetition and alternation operators apply to the preceding subpattern.\\
    $|$ & Alternation.\\
    $[ ]$ & Delimit a set of characters. Ranges are specified as [x-y].\\
    \textasciicircum & Anchor the pattern to the beginning of the string. Only when first.\\
    \$ & Anchor the pattern to the end of the string. Only when last.\\
\end{longtable}
%\end{center}
```

When compiled, this looks exactly like your `table`, provided you include [`\usepackage{longtable}`](https://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) in your preamble (and `longtable`s are not floats, while `table`s are).