# Prevent LaTeX deluxetable from starting on new page

Tags: latex

I have a giant deluxetable (~4 pages long) that I want to start on the same page as my section header. I'm very new to LaTeX so I'm not sure how to achieve this. I'm using `\documentclass[preprint]{aastex}`. Here's a snippet of my code:

```
\section{Additional Tables}

\begin{deluxetable}{rrrrrr}
\tablecolumns{6}
\tablewidth{0pc}
\tablecaption{Observational Data}
\tablehead{\colhead{Object} & \colhead{SpT} & \colhead{Night Observed} & \colhead{J$_\text{s}$-Band} & \colhead{H-Band} & \colhead{K$_\text{s}$-Band}}
\startdata
\textbf{2M0106} & L0 & 9 Sep 2014 & \ding{51} &  \ding{51}   & \ding{51}\\
% way more rows of data...
\enddata
\end{deluxetable}
```

I've seen some fixes for normal tables that unnecessarily start on a new page (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648178/table-unnecessarily-starting-from-next-page-in-latex)) but I don't know enough LaTeX to apply that to my deluxetable. Any help you could give me would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to make `longtable` look very similar to `deluxetable` on [this website](http://www2.astro.psu.edu/gradinfo/psuthesis/longtable.html). It works pretty well.

```
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{lll}
%Here is the caption, the stuff in [] is the table of contents entry,
%the stuff in {} is the title that will appear on the first page of the
%table.
\caption[Feasible triples for a highly variable Grid]{Feasible triples
for highly variable Grid, MLMMH.} \label{grid_mlmmh} \\

%This is the header for the first page of the table...
\hline \hline \\[-2ex]
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Time (s)}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Triple chosen}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Other feasible triples}} \\[0.5ex] \hline
\\[-1.8ex]
\endfirsthead

%This is the header for the remaining page(s) of the table...
\multicolumn{3}{c}{{\tablename} \thetable{} -- Continued} \\[0.5ex]
\hline \hline \\[-2ex]
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Time (s)}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Triple chosen}} &
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Other feasible triples}} \\[0.5ex] \hline
\\[-1.8ex]
\endhead

%This is the footer for all pages except the last page of the table...
\multicolumn{3}{l}{{Continued on Next Page\ldots}} \\
\endfoot

%This is the footer for the last page of the table...
\\[-1.8ex] \hline \hline
\endlastfoot

%Now the data...
0 & (1, 11, 13725) & (1, 12, 10980), (1, 13, 8235), (2, 2, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
2745 & (1, 12, 10980) & (1, 13, 8235), (2, 2, 0), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
5490 & (1, 12, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
8235 & (1, 12, 16470) & (1, 13, 13725), (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
% <data removed>
164700 & (1, 13, 13725) & (2, 2, 2745), (2, 3, 0), (3, 1, 0) \\
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```